# Looking for a way to check if a word is in the list of not

Tags: python, class

Implement three classes: VerbWord, NounWord and Dict. The VerbWord is for representing a verb and the NounWord is for representing a noun.

Each of the VerbWord and NounWord should take a string as a parameter of the constructor. Assume that this string is the infinitive/singular of the word they represent, e.g. VerbWord('move') creates an object representing the word 'move'. Also, each of the VerbWord and NounWord should define instance functions get_forms() that return various forms of their word.

Assume that verbs have the following forms: infinitive, infinitive with 'ed', infinitive with 'ing' and infinitive with 's', e.g. move, moved, moving and moves. Note that the second form in this example is 'moved', not 'moveed'; if the verb ends with 'e' then you should only add 'd' to it. Nouns have two forms: singular and plural (with 's' added).

The Dict should store a list of verbs and nouns; use instance variable 'words' to store this list. It should also have instance method 'add_word' that takes a VerbWord or NounWord object as a parameter and adds it to the list, and instance method 'is_known' that takes a string as a parameter and returns True if the given string is a word from the dictionary, in any of its forms.

Below is my code, when I add only one word to the dict, it is working while it is not working when I add more than one word.

```
class VerbWord:
  def __init__(self,verb):
    self.verb = verb
  def get_forms(self):
    listOfForms = []
    listOfForms.append(self.verb)
    listOfForms.append(self.verb+"s")
    listOfForms.append(self.verb+"ing")
    if self.verb[-1] == "e":
      listOfForms.append(self.verb+"d")
    else:
      listOfForms.append(self.verb+"ed")
    return listOfForms
    
class NounWord:
  def __init__(self,noun):
    self.noun = noun
  def get_forms(self):
    listOfForms = []
    listOfForms.append(self.noun)
    listOfForms.append(self.noun+"s")
    return listOfForms

class Dict:
  def __init__(self):
    self.words = []
    
  def add_word(self,word):
    self.words.append(word)
 
  def is_known(self,word):
    for w in self.words:
      a = w.get_forms()
      if word in a:
        return True
      else:
        return False
```

The expect outcome:

```
dict = Dict()
dict.add_word(NounWord("star"))
print(dict.is_known("stars"))
dict.add_word(NounWord("create"))
print(dict.is_known("create"))
```

True
True

What I got is
True
False

Comment: You should not `return False` in `is_known()` until the entire list (`self.words`) has been checked.

Comment: Hi Johnny, thanks for your reply, may I know what does the entire has been checked mean? As I think that it has already done through the for loop?

Comment: As soon as `if word in a:` is `False` you `return`. So if the 1st word is not a match you never check any words after that.

Comment: You should also revisit naming a `list` a `Dict` just to keep the logic of things in alignment with the existence of things

Answer (score 0):

You are returning result of the check against the very first word in the list, regardless of if there was a match or not. Instead, you want to check if any word matched, and return False only if none of them did:

```
    def is_known(self,word):
        for w in self.words:
            a = w.get_forms()
            if word in a:
                return True
        return False
```

With your previous code, you first matched "create" with "star" and because it is not a match, you `return False` - as return stops execution of the function, nothing else even got a chance to match.